# Vampire Inquisitors and going into places uninvited?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

Can a Vampire with the Inquisitor class go into anybody's house uninvited?

Answer (score 5):

**Not automatically.**

As per the description for [Vampires](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/vampire/):

> Vampires cannot enter a private home or dwelling unless invited in by someone with the authority to do so.

The [Inquisitor](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/inquisitor/) class does not inherently offer a character any authority to arbitrarily go where they please. What they are allowed to do and where they are allowed to go depends on their position in society, not their class (though their position in society may be influenced by their class and skills).

A vampire that is a member of an organisation which does have the legal authority to arbitrarily enter people's houses could conceivably invite themselves into someone else's home. For instance, a vampire officer in the City Watch might have the authority to enter properties if they are in pursuit of a criminal or conducting an investigation, in which case they would be able to enter a private residence without needing anyone else's permission.

In your setting, it could be the case that Inquisitors of a particular religion do have the legal authority to enter private property in order to investigate heresy or other wrongdoing, but that would depend on the religion, and the region. Inquisitors of the dominant religion in a theocratic state probably would have the right to enter private properties, but you would not expect an Inquisitor who follows a human deity to be accorded any special respect or authority in a Dwarven fortress or Elven village, for instance, or for an Inquisitor of an evil god to be considered an authority in places dominated by a good-aligned religion. In a more secular region, the legal system may not grant any authority to any religion.

Comment: Wow, talk about great minds thinking alike - snap! :)

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Vampire Weaknesses](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/vampire#Weaknesses) -

> Vampires cannot enter a private home or dwelling unless invited in by someone with the authority to do so.

Being a member of a character class does not, in general, provide any sort of authority or in-game membership in any societys or groups. So, no, possessing Inquisitor class levels will not overcome this weakness.

About the only way I can see to overcome this weakness in any form via a class would be to take levels in one of the Hell Knight classes, and perhaps then, in Cheliax on Golarion, you might be able to justify having legal authority to enter private homes, but this would still be a GM call.